# How to read data from a csv table in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a csv file, and I want to extract the each column a as string so I can use it with `getSymbols` function from `quantmod` package.

The csv file looks like this:

```
AEGR,Aegerion Pharmaceuticals Inc
AKS,AK Steel Holding Corp
ALXA‎,Alexza Pharmaceuticals Inc
CCL‎,Carnival Corporation
CECO‎,Career Education Corp
CDXS‎,Codexis Inc
```

And I use this code to read the file:

```
data<-read.csv(file='CAPM/allquotes.csv',header=F)
symbols=gettext(data[,1])
symbol.names=gettext(data[,2])
getSymbols(symbols)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ALXA‎&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=5&e=16&f=2012&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=ALXA‎&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

When I enter the symbols one by one it works fine. I've also noticed that when I go to the end of the last line, the margins seem to corrupt. In the image you can see that values of 'symbols', the end of the line is a few more spaces to the right than it should be (you can see that because of the color of the initial parenthesis).

[image: symbols object]

Comment: Somewhere in your code a non existing file is downloaded. Could you add the output of `traceback()`, called just after you got the error. This can show what the sequence of commands whas that lead to the error.

Comment: There is a [left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) in "ALXA"

Comment: I did the traceback():

4: download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m, 
       "&b=", sprintf("%.2d", from.d), "&c=", from.y, "&d=", to.m, 
       "&e=", sprintf("%.2d", to.d), "&f=", to.y, "&g=d&q=q&y=0", 
       "&z=", Symbols.name, "&x=.csv", sep = ""), destfile = tmp, 
       quiet = !verbose)
3: getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = c("AEGR", "AKS", "ALXA‎", "CCL‎", 
   "CECO‎", "CDXS‎", "DAL", "DAN", "DDD‎", "DY", "END", "EWG‎", 
   "EWH‎", "EWI‎", "EWJ‎", "EWP‎", "EWQ‎", "EWU", "FEZ‎", 
   "FITB", "FSZ", "FXI‎", "GREK", "HES‎", "JASO‎", "NLSN", 
   "NQ‎", "NUE", "OSH",

Comment: "PDC", "PIN‎", "PIR‎", "PLW", "SUN‎", 
   "USO‎", "VGK‎", "VLO‎", "WDC", "X‎", "XLF‎", "XLK", 
   "ZNGA‎"), env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE, warnings = TRUE, 
       auto.assign = TRUE)
2: do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols, 
       env = env, verbose = verbose, warnings = warnings, auto.assign = auto.assign, 
       ...))
1: getSymbols(symbols)

## End of output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your csv has hidden characters in it -- namely a left-to-right mark.  Since you are using RStudio, you can remove it with `gsub` using "\016" as the value for the `pattern` argument.  Alternatively, instead of removing the hidden character that you don't want, you could only keep the characters that you know you DO want.  For example, if your symbols will only have letters and/or numbers you could use something like `gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", data[, 1])`

```
data <- read.csv(text="AEGR,Aegerion Pharmaceuticals Inc
AKS,AK Steel Holding Corp
ALXA‎,Alexza Pharmaceuticals Inc
CCL‎,Carnival Corporation
CECO‎,Career Education Corp
CDXS‎,Codexis Inc", header=FALSE)
#data[, 1] <- gsub("\016", "", data[, 1]) #this should work in RStudio
data[, 1] <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", data[, 1]) #but this should work anywhere
symbols=gettext(data[,1])
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo')
```

After you `read.csv`, you can examine the `data` object to see that something is amiss.

```
s <- as.character(data[, 1])
str(s)
#chr [1:6] "AEGR" "AKS" "ALXA""| __truncated__ "CCL""| __truncated__ "CECO""| __truncated__ "CDXS""| __truncated__
str(s[3])
#chr "ALXA""| __truncated__

charToRaw(s[3])
#[1] 41 4c 58 41 e2 80 8e
# Compare what we have to what we think we have
charToRaw("ALXA")
#[1] 41 4c 58 41
```

Comment: I think you identified the problem but the solution doesn't work completely. The hidden characters don't appear in the symbols variable until I edit them manually. After that I tried both of your methods and they worked perfectly.

Comment: All I have to work with is the data you gave in your question. ;-) I don't have your csv.

Comment: How does that get introduced?  Using your definition for 'data' (before the fix), nchar(as.character(data[3,1])) returns 5, while nchar(gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", data[, 1])[3]) returns 4.

Comment: @GSee Pasting your definition for 'data' into a text file, I see the character sequences "b nul  so" (od -a output) immediately ALXA.  I do not see these characters with "view source" in my browser.  What's going on, and how did you spot it?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I copied/pasted the data from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Systematic Investor Toolbox, that uses the quantmod. Thanks to GSee, the solution came this way:

```
source('SystematicInvestorToolbox.r')
load.packages('quantmod')
dates='2012::2012'
data<-read.csv(file='CAPM/allquotes.csv',header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
data[, 1] <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", data[, 1])
symbols=gettext(data[,1])
symbol.names=gettext(data[,2])
ia=aa.test.create.ia.custom(symbols,symbol.names,dates)
plot.ia(ia,(1:1))
```

It's worth noting that the left-to-right marks only appear with 'symbols' not when I extract the characters for the names of the quotes in 'symbol.names'.

Thanks for the help.